# Redirect the stdout when loading package in Tcl

Tags: tcl

I would like to redirect the stdout to null when loading package in Windows Tcl. (Redirect the wording of "Quality Windows Audio/Video Experience (qWAVE) support is available." to null)

Is their any way to solve this or any idea for this ?? Thank you so much.

```
C:\Users\Tester>tclsh
%       set ixchariot_installation_dir "C:/Program Files x86)/Ixia/IxChariot"
C:/Program Files (x86)/Ixia/IxChariot
%       cd $ixchariot_installation_dir
%       load ChariotExt
Quality Windows Audio/Video Experience (qWAVE) support is available.
```

Comment: The hard part is undoing the redirect afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

If the library is using Tcl channels to write its message, and you're using Tcl 8.6, it's pretty easy. You just push a transform on the `stdout` channel that swallows all bytes.

```
# Most of this is boiler-plate stuff...
namespace eval swallow {
    proc initialize {handle mode} {
        return {initialize clear finalize write flush}
    }
    proc clear {handle} {}
    proc finalize {handle} {}
    proc flush {handle} {}
    # The important one; do nothing to throw away bytes
    proc write {handle buffer} {}
    # Export as an ensemble
    namespace export *
    namespace ensemble create
}

# Start dropping output
chan push stdout swallow
load ChariotExt
# Stop dropping output
chan pop stdout
```

That *only* works if the library is using Tcl channels to write it's message. If it is using a direct write (the more likely case) it won't. You can instead try a full redirect, but these are not easily undone.

```
close stdout
open NUL
load ChariotExt
```

I know that'd work on POSIX systems (except with `/dev/null` instead of `NUL`). Not sure on Windows. And ***it can't be easily undone;*** the old standard output stream is gone.

And in any case, it's possible that the library is using a direct write to the console; those aren't blockable, and you might just have to live with that irritating message.

Comment: On a posix platform, you could use a few ways to do a redirect as a different FD, but they're getting non-trivial.